# How to not export the Slave server connections in the Pentaho XML files?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pdi

When I try to export the Pentaho Job or Transformation. It also exports the Slave server connection details and DB connections. I prevented the DB connection information by making use of the JNDI but need help with the Slave server connections. Please help out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spoon. Under tools then options there is a check box that says only output used connections. Check that box. Restart your spoon. Should fix your problem. thanks

Comment: I tried it but still i get the slave server details in the XML file